# How to conditionally remove all rows associated with a factor/

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

In the dummy data, contains "3" sets of subdata. If any of the rows in the data is negative, then I want to completely remove all the rows associated with that set.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), rep = 6),
                 y = rnorm(30, 1, 1),
                 set =rep(c(1:3), each = 10))

 df$set <- as.factor(df$set)
```

So here, only the rows related to Set `1` is retained as all the values are positive. The other two sets need to be removed.

```
  x       y      set
1  A  0.3735462   1
2  B  1.1836433   1
3  C  0.1643714   1
4  D  2.5952808   1
5  E  1.3295078   1
6  A  0.1795316   1
7  B  1.4874291   1
8  C  1.7383247   1
9  D  1.5757814   1
10 E  0.6946116   1
11 A  2.5117812   2
12 B  1.3898432   2
13 C  0.3787594   2
14 D -1.2146999   2
15 E  2.1249309   2
16 A  0.9550664   2
17 B  0.9838097   2
18 C  1.9438362   2
19 D  1.8212212   2
20 E  1.5939013   2
21 A  1.9189774   3
22 B  1.7821363   3
23 C  1.0745650   3
24 D -0.9893517   3
25 E  1.6198257   3
26 A  0.9438713   3
27 B  0.8442045   3
28 C -0.4707524   3
29 D  0.5218499   3
30 E  1.4179416   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by set, then filter only the groups in which `all` values of `y` are greater than 0

```
library(dplyr)

#with dplyr <1.1.0 (but still current, this approach is not deprecated):

df %>% 
    group_by(set) %>% 
    filter(all(y > 0)) %>% 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   x         y set  
   <chr> <dbl> <fct>
 1 A     0.374 1    
 2 B     1.18  1    
 3 C     0.164 1    
 4 D     2.60  1    
 5 E     1.33  1    
 6 A     0.180 1    
 7 B     1.49  1    
 8 C     1.74  1    
 9 D     1.58  1    
10 E     0.695 1  

# With dplyr 1.1.0

df %>% 
    filter(all(y > 0), .by = set)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @GuedesBF's solution better, but an alternative:

```
df %>%
  add_count(set, wt = y < 0) %>%
  filter(n == 0) %>% 
  select(-n) # if you want to remove the helper column
```